# JanusGraph database cache on distributed setup

Tags: database, caching, cassandra, janusgraph, gremlin-server

In a multi node Janusgraph cluster, data modification done from one instance does not sync with others until it reaches the given expiry time (`cache.db-cache-time`)

As per the documentation[1] it does not recommends to enable database level cache in a distributed setup as cached data does not share amoung instances.

Any suggestions for a solution/workaround where i can see the data changes from other JG instances immediately and avoid stale data access ?

[1] https://docs.janusgraph.org/operations/cache/#cache-expiration-time

Answer (score 2):

If you want immediate access to the most up-to-date version of the data then by definition, you cannot cache any of it.

The contents of the cache will be accessed as long as they have not expired or been evicted. Unfortunately there is no way around it if consistency is your top priority. Cheers!